# Insert and show data SQL server 2008 to Blackberry native app

Tags: sql, database, blackberry

i want to ask about development in blackberry. I have background in .Net. If i want to develop an native application in BB to do data insert operations in Ms.SQL server 2008 database from blackberry. what should i learn and what should i do ? thank you for your advice.

Any sample on this ?

--Raghav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, see [short introduction to Blackberry UI structure](http://us.blackberry.com/devjournals/resources/journals/jul_2005/gui_part_1.jsp).

For described task we may create [UiApplication](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiApplication.html).

Then, we should have 3 kind of screens (we can use [MainScreen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/MainScreen.html) class):

1. for list of records, where we can use [ListField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ListField.html) UI control
2. for detail view, where we can use [LabelField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/LabelField.html) UI controls
3. for new record creation, with [EditField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/EditField.html) UI controls

Also, you can use [ButtonField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ButtonField.html) UI controls and [MenuItem](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/MenuItem.html) menu actions

On Blackberry we can use REST or SOAP web services to transfer data on server side

On server side we can use connection to SQL database to complete CRUD actions

See also:

[J2ME REST Client](http://www.acidum.de/2008/12/29/j2me-rest-client/)

[How to build and run a J2ME Web service application](http://www.cs.wichita.edu/~chang/lecture/cs898t/program/how-j2me-webservice.html)